# How can npm install always throwing error code 1?

Tags: reactjs, npm

Every time I use `npm install` it always shows this error. I have already downgraded my Node.js to the latest stable version.

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! git dep preparation failed
npm ERR! command C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\AZ PRODUCTIONS\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js install --force --cache=C:\Users\AZ PRODUCTIONS\AppData\Local\npm-cache --prefer-offline=false --prefer-online=false --offline=false --no-progress --no-save --no-audit --include=dev --include=peer --include=optional --no-package-lock-only --no-dry-run
npm ERR! > spookyswap-sdk@1.2.0 prepare
npm ERR! > rm -rf ./dist && yarn build
```

I can't post more because of the limitation.

Comment: Code blocks are fenced with _backticks_ (`\``), not single quote (`'`). And I'm sure you can post a bit more of the error, or at least a more helpful section. What does it say before this?

Answer (score 1):

`npm clear cache --force`
and delete node_modules and package-lock.json
try
`npm i --force`